# Syntax error: insert to complete classbody and mainclass

Tags: java, syntax-error, bukkit

Getting this syntax error when coding, I can't seem to find the source of the problem if any one knows place comment as quickly as possible thanks.

```
package me.carwyn123;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Staffviewer extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Staffviewer plugin now enabled / plugin made by carwyn123");
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Staffviewer as been disabled / plugin made by carwyn123");
        saveConfig();
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String Label, String[] args) {

        // the staff list code

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staff") && sender instanceof Player) {
            if ( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.staff")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You don't                                               have permission");
                return true;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "================================");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "        Staff members");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "================================");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + getConfig().getString("staffmembers"));
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "================================");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA +  getConfig().getString("staffmembers"));
            return true;

        }


        // staff help code
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffhelp") && sender instanceof Player) {
            if ( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.help")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You don't    have permission");
                return true;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Here is the list    of commands" );            
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "---------------------------------");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "/staff : gives the list of staff");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "/staffadd: adds staff to the list, using config allows for more design");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "/staffhelp: gets you to this page");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "/staffinfo:    gives you information about the plugin");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "---------------------------------");

            return true;

        }
        // staff information

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffinfo") && sender instanceof Player)  {
            if( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.info")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You don't have permission");
                return true ;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Here you will   find information about the plugin");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "--------------------------------------------------------------------");    
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + " This plugin was made by carwyn123");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + " If you find any bugs, please report as a ticked or commet on bukkit.dev");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + " Thanks for downloading this plugin, from the team");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "--------------------------------------------------------------------");
            return true;

        }



        // staff add code
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffadd")); {
            if ( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.add")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You don't have permission");
                return true ;
            }

            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You can't add know one");
                return true;

            }
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                str.append(args[i] + " ");
            }
            String staffmembers = str.toString();
            getConfig().set("staffmembers", staffmembers);
            saveConfig();
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You have added a staff member"); 

            return true;


        // staff line editor 
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffedit")); {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.edit")) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You don't have permission");
                return true;
            }     
            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You need to add a   message");
            return true;
            }
            StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                str1.append(args[i] + " ");
            }
            String staffedit = str1.toString(); 
            getConfig().set("endline", staffedit);
            saveConfig();
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA + "You have added a message at the end"); 
            return true;

        }
    }
```

The problem has been happening for about 2 hours now. I have searched a lot of sources on the internet and this seems to be a well known problem with people that are new to coding.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I've edited your question for you. Please __format__, and __comment through__ your code yourself next time - The formatter that comes with your IDE is helpful and it improves the readability of these questions.

Answer (score 2):

Add import declaration for `org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;`, change it to

```
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
```

And add a `}` at the end to complete the class.

Answer (score 0):

You had several errors in your code and you wrote `ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA` several times, so I made a prefix variable for it.
Your final code is this:

```
package me.carwyn123;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Staffviewer extends JavaPlugin {
    String prefix=ChatColor.GOLD + "[StaffViewer]" + ChatColor.AQUA;
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Staffviewer plugin now enabled / plugin made by carwyn123");
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Staffviewer as been disabled / plugin made by carwyn123");
        saveConfig();
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String Label, String[] args) {

        // the staff list code

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staff") && sender instanceof Player) {
            if ( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.staff")) {
                sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You don't have permission");
                return true;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "================================");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "        Staff members");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "================================");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + getConfig().getString("staffmembers"));
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "================================");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA +  getConfig().getString("staffmembers"));
            return true;

        }


        // staff help code
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffhelp") && sender instanceof Player) {
            if ( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.help")) {
                sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You don't    have permission");
                return true;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage(prefix + "Here is the list    of commands" );            
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "---------------------------------");
            player.sendMessage(prefix + "/staff : gives the list of staff");
            player.sendMessage(prefix + "/staffadd: adds staff to the list, using config allows for more design");
            player.sendMessage(prefix + "/staffhelp: gets you to this page");
            player.sendMessage(prefix + "/staffinfo:    gives you information about the plugin");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "---------------------------------");

            return true;

        }
        // staff information

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffinfo") && sender instanceof Player)  {
            if( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.info")) {
                sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You don't have permission");
                return true ;
            }

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage(prefix + "Here you will   find information about the plugin");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "--------------------------------------------------------------------");    
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + " This plugin was made by carwyn123");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + " If you find any bugs, please report as a ticked or commet on bukkit.dev");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + " Thanks for downloading this plugin, from the team");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "--------------------------------------------------------------------");
            return true;

        }



        // staff add code
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffadd")){
            if ( !sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.add")) {
                sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You don't have permission");
                return true ;
            }

            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You can't add know one");
                return true;

            }
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                str.append(args[i] + " ");
            }
            String staffmembers = str.toString();
            getConfig().set("staffmembers", staffmembers);
            saveConfig();
            sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You have added a staff member"); 

            return true;
        }

        // staff line editor 
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("staffedit")){
            if (!sender.hasPermission("staffviewer.edit")) {
                sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You don't have permission");
                return true;
            }     
            if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You need to add a   message");
                return true;
            }
            StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                str1.append(args[i] + " ");
            }
            String staffedit = str1.toString(); 
            getConfig().set("endline", staffedit);
            saveConfig();
            sender.sendMessage(prefix + "You have added a message at the end"); 
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing "Your code was terrible" is a terrible thing to say.. consider a more polite way, you don't want to discourage people from learning a programming language.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, I repaired it.